# Pypsark function to concatenate unique values of different columns

Tags: python, pyspark

EDITED
below is just an example of df, i need a scalable solution. the actual df has 30+ columns (p1,p2,p3,.... and so on).

I have a df like this -

```
+---+---+----+
| id| p1| p2 |
+---+---+------
|foo|[1]| null|
|bar|[2]| [2] |
|loo|[3]| [4] |
+---+---+-----+
```

I want an output like this -

```
+---+---+----+--------+
| id| p1| p2 | concat |
+---+---+------+------+
|foo|[1]| null|  [1]  |
|bar|[2]| [2] |  [2]  |
|loo|[3]| [4] |  [3,4]|
+---+---+-----+--------
```

So the new column concat will only hold unique values from the p1 and p2 column
I have tried F.concat() method in pyspark but it is not giving the desires result.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what's your spark version?

Answer (score 0):

Hi to concat values if there are unique, you can use the below code. I used the lambda function to analyze all DataFrame rows and declare check_unique_vlaues() which return uniques values for the analyzed row.

```
def check_unique_vlaues(first, second):
    if first == second:
        return first
    else:
        return [first, second]

df['p3'] = df.apply(lambda x: check_unique_vlaues(x.p1, x.p2), axis=1)
```

**EDIT:**

To get unique values from all columns in a row without first we can use `unique()` function which is available for pandas Series.

```
def func(row):
    row = row[1:]
    return row.unique()

df['concat'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one would be hard to scale for me, the above df posted is just an example, in real i have 30+ columns which need to be compared and return only unique values from it

Comment: OK, I understand, I will try to improve the code and after that, I will edit answer.

Comment: Please check my answer after edited and give me feedback if it's work as you want

Comment: didn't work for me. i had to change my pyspark dataframe to pandas for the above implementation. the conversion failed because the number of rows i am dealing with is 500 million +

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` functions if you have Spark 2.4+

```
df.withColumn("concat", F.array_union(df.p1, df.p2))\
    .withColumn("concat", F.array_distinct(df.concat)).show()
```

For Spark 2.3 and below,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def concat_array(col1, col2):
     return list(set((list() if col1 is None else col1) + (list() if col2 is None else col2)))

concat_array_udf = F.udf(concat_array, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df.withColumn('concat', concat_array_udf(df.p1, df.p2)).show()
+---+---+----+------+
| id| p1|  p2|concat|
+---+---+----+------+
|foo|[1]|null|   [1]|
|bar|[2]| [2]|   [2]|
|loo|[3]| [4]|[3, 4]|
+---+---+----+------+
```

Comment: array_union only takes 2 array as input, i missed details in the initial question. The solution need to be scalable. In actual i have 30+ columns (p1,p2,p3,......)